# A "rearrangement" of a finite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $T$ be a set of sets.

Let $\equiv$ be an equivalence relation on $\bigcup T$ defined by the formula $$a\equiv b \Leftrightarrow \forall X\in T:(a\in X\Leftrightarrow b\in X).$$

Let $S$ be a partition of $\bigcup T$ induced by the equivalence $\equiv$. In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927969/terms-for-particular-equivalence-relation-and-partition) I've asked for a name of $S$. I was not told a name. So lets call $S$ the *rearrangement* of $T$.

Question: Can we prove that if $T$ is finite then $S$ is also finite?

Comment: @Hippalectryon I tried to meditate a half of minute and had no ideas

Comment: An entire half of a minute! Amazing.

Comment: Hint: If $T$ has $n$ elements, then $S$ has at most $2^n$ elements.

Comment: @porton Yes, we can.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Maybe this is an eclipse in my mind. Why $S$ has at most $2^n$ elements?

Comment: It was a hint for a reason. Until you show some effort, why would we give you an answer?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I am stalled in the attempt to figure out the property of equivalence relations which corresponds to finiteness. Why would you not give me an answer? It is not a homework

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I feel that I am near to the answer. Probably I need to select a canonical representative element from every equivalence class

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I've spent more then a hour trying to prove this. I feel I am very near to the solution, but something prevents me to find it. Please explain how to derive the solution. It is not a homework and your help won't harm

Comment: For pairwise non-equivalent elements $a_0, \ldots, a_k$ we have $\forall i, j
\in \{ 0, \ldots, k \} : (i \neq j \Rightarrow a_i \not\in X_{i, j} \wedge a_j
\in X_{i, j})$ where $X_{i, j} \in T$. How to derive that $k \leqslant 2^n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having an equivalence class $C$, we can find the set $f \in 2^T$ of all $X \in
T$ such that $a \in X$ for all $a \in C$. $b \equiv a \Leftrightarrow \forall
X \in T : (a \in X \Leftrightarrow b \in X) \Leftrightarrow \forall X \in T :
(X \in f \Leftrightarrow b \in X)$. So $C = \left\{ b \in \bigcup T
\mid b \equiv a \right\}$ can be restored knowing $f$.

Consequently there are no more than $\operatorname{card} 2^T = 2^{\operatorname{card} T}$ classes.